# Is it bad performance when fetching data using LOCAL-URL-API such as http://127.0.0.1/data-api.php?action=students&grade=1&page=2

Tags: php

I would like to use PHP to write a website, which I need good performance.

I want to use api-style to get json-formatted-data. For example,

If someone want a page to show the 2nd page(50 students per page) of the 1st Grade students, he access the following URL in the browser, such as

```
http://mywebsite.com/student-list.php?grade=1&page=2.
```

Inside the above PHP script, I first send a request using curl/file_get_contents to the following link to fetch json-formatted-data:

```
http://localhost/API/data-api.php?action=students&grade=1&page=2
```

In ./API/data-api.php, I use $_GET to get the params, and fetch data from database as needed, I may reform the data to an array. Maybe then foreach the array to add a little other customized things to the array, THEN JSON_ENCODE THE ARRAY, AND ECHO IT AS THE LAST OF THE FILE.
(Maybe I also should use content-type:application/json at the head of this data-api.php file? I also will add some memcached logic to cache the data when fetching, that's some other things not involved in this question.)

Maybe I would also use this way to fetch other data from other api-files in this student-list.php. Then show them all in the html template.

The question is : IS THIS WAY OK?

I know single user using the website may be just ok, but is the performance good when there's 2000 or more people accessing the same page? Because I'm using this '

```
http://localhost/API/data-api.php...
```

thing, is there some network-delay thing involved? and I use curl/file_get_contents to fetch data from the API file, is this way consuming huge CPU resources? I just want to make the data-json-like and seperate the data-layer from my other view/controller layer as maximum as possible.

I'm stuck at it, don't know whether I should use this way to start writing the website? Cause once I started it will be hard to change.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: It's never as good as if you use the database directly in your application because you have HTTP overhead etc. But I think it'll work for 2000 users.

Comment: why don't you use ajax for request instead of server side's curl?

Comment: I think... there may be possibilities of failure when using ajax to fetch data during bad network. What if they are important data that cannot  be failed even user in bad network?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER, what about 20000 people....and sorry that I don't understand what you've said...I just want the data to be accessed like an api, cause maybe 2 years later I may change the database from mysql to oracle, maybe move the database to another server.

Comment: What about I do not use the http://localhost/API/data-api.php format, and change to ./API/data-api.php? Are there differences? cause in my eyes the second is like server-side file-accessing without network...

Comment: @Daniel well then work with a separated model which is coded against interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should try to read some PHP frameworks, see how they work...